# Output of Dockerfile not equal to output of same commands run inside container

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm confused about some behavior in Docker. I have a minimal Dockerfile running on an OSX host:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y gcc \
  build-essential \
  libmysqlclient-dev

RUN \
  echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password womp | debconf-set-selections && \
  echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password womp | debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

I build this image with:

```
docker build --tag wonk --file Dockerfile .
```

Then I create a container for this image via:

```
docker run -dit wonk
```

Then I find the container's id:

```
docker ps -a
```

And use that to drop a shell inside the container:

```
docker exec -it {{ CONTAINER_ID }} /bin/bash
```

If I then try to start the mysql server from inside the client:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

but this fails.

**However**, if I remove the entire second RUN command from my docker file, repeat the steps above, and then run the second RUN command inside the container, I'm able to start mysql.

Does anyone know why this would be the case? Any suggestions would be very helpful!

---

EDIT: In fact while the version of mysql is identical in the two containers described above, the one that installs mysql-server in the Dockerfile ends up with directories `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/run/mysqld`, but those directories are not present in the container wherein I install mysql-server from inside the container. Why would that be?

---

Contents of /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2019-09-18T23:39:50.957874Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-09-18T23:39:50.981668Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2019-09-18T23:39:51.162825Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-09-18T23:39:51.164124Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 3456 ...
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168209Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168258Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168289Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168349Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-09-18T23:39:51.168719Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-09-18T23:39:51.169949Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-09-18T23:39:51.178954Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-18T23:39:51.181161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-09-18T23:39:51.194860Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.216975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-09-18T23:39:51.217101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-09-18T23:39:51.285152Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.287382Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.287434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.288015Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-18T23:39:51.339200Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.27 started; log sequence number 2625955
2019-09-18T23:39:51.340684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-09-18T23:39:51.340844Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.343146Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190918 23:39:51
2019-09-18T23:39:51.346475Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-09-18T23:39:51.346536Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-09-18T23:39:51.346580Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-09-18T23:39:51.346631Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.353776Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table storage engine for 'proxies_priv' doesn't have this option
2019-09-18T23:39:51.353845Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.353946Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-09-18T23:39:51.354042Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354162Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354209Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354246Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354283Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354318Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354355Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354390Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354461Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354496Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354531Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354574Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354612Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354647Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354683Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354718Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354753Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354788Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354823Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354859Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354897Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354933Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.354968Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355003Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355039Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355074Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355109Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355145Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355180Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355215Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355251Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355286Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355321Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355357Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355392Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355583Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-09-18T23:39:51.355914Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-09-18T23:39:51.462147Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-09-18T23:39:51.462633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190918 23:39:51
2019-09-18T23:39:52.922232Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2625974
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925597Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925658Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925694Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925728Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925763Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925800Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925902Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.925936Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.926081Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2019-09-18T23:39:52.926560Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-09-18T23:39:53.037681Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: Could you add to question the failure logs you face by running `/etc/init.d/mysql start` inside container?

Comment: Sure thing. I wiped the logs, reran the start command once, and copied the content that was then written into the error log above.